# list of two dataframes, if I change elements of list (dataframes), will the dataframes change

Tags: python, dataframe

I am working on the titanic problem from kaggle. In the data preprocessing steps, I want to combine train and test dataframes. So, I made a variable combine like this.

```
combine = [df_train, df_test]
```

I saw the unusual behavior, the train and test dataframes get updated automatically if I change the elements within the combine variable.

```
for dataset in combine:
    dataset['Title'] = dataset.Name.str.extract(' ([A-Za-z]+)\.', expand=False)
    print(dataset["Title"].unique())

for dataset in combine:
    dataset['Title'] = dataset['Title'].replace(['Lady', 'Countess','Capt', 'Col',\
    'Don', 'Dr', 'Major', 'Rev', 'Sir', 'Jonkheer', 'Dona'], 'Rare')

    dataset['Title'] = dataset['Title'].replace('Mlle', 'Miss')
    dataset['Title'] = dataset['Title'].replace('Ms', 'Miss')
    dataset['Title'] = dataset['Title'].replace('Mme', 'Mrs')
```

After doing this, I checked the df_train, it has "Title" column.

Then, I tried this.
If I drop the column from df_train by doing this

```
df_train = df_train.drop(["Ticket", "Cabin"], axis=1)
df_test = df_test.drop(["Ticket", "Cabin"], axis = 1)
```

After dropping these two columns directly from the dataframes, combine variable doesn't get updated itself.

I want to undertand how does df_train gets updated when I changed the elements inside the combine variable. But If I change the df_train and df_test directly as described above by dropping the columns, the combine variable doesn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simplified example:

```
>>> info = [1,2]
>>> other = {'hello': 'world'}
>>> combined = [info, other]
>>> combined[0].append(567)
>>> combined, info
([[1, 2, 567], {'hello': 'world'}], [1, 2, 567])
>>> combined[1]['one'] = 1
>>> combined, info
([[1, 2, 567], {'hello': 'world', 'one': 1}], [1, 2, 567])
>>> combined, other
([[1, 2, 567], {'hello': 'world', 'one': 1}], {'hello': 'world', 'one': 1})
>>> info = [0]
>>> combined, info
([[1, 2, 567], {'hello': 'world', 'one': 1}], [0])
```

Methods like `append` and `__setitem__` (a.k.a. `thing['key'] = stuff`) modify the original object in-place. Putting an object into a list doesn't necessarily copy it, and in this case, it's putting into the list *pointers to these objects*, so, for example, `combined[0].append(567)` actually modifies the object called `info` *through the pointer stored in `combined`*.

Note that now the same object (!) has two references: the name `info` and the object `combined`. Rebinding the name `info` to a *different object* in `info = [0]` should delete the old object, right? Well, yes, but only if said name was the only reference to that object. In our case, there were *two*, as discussed earlier, so the second reference lives, and the object itself lives. Now `info` is bound to an entirely different object and doesn't affect the old one, which can still be accessed with `combined[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, lists are mutable, and every object is referencing some space in memory.

In this case, your combine is referencing to the same space in memory as df_train and df_test. Well actually, your combine has it's own unique space in memory, but it's memory for index 0 and index 1, is identical to the memory space of df_train and df_test.

Here's an example:

```
arr_1 = [1, 3, 5]
arr_2 = [3, 6, 7]
arr_3 = [arr_1, arr_2]
print(id(arr_3), id(arr_1))
```

Here, the memory location of both arrays are different, which makes sense. arr_3 occupies a unique space in memory. But,

```
print(id(arr_3[0]), id(arr_1))
```

reveals that the first index of arr_3, has the exact same memory address as arr_1, which means they are both pointing to the same piece of data.

Therefore, if you change anything in either arr_3[0] or arr_1, you're changing the same piece of data. This is the essence of mutability.

Now in your situation, when you drop a column, it's not going to affect the combine object, because drop is not being done in place. You're reassigning df_train to a new dataframe, which effectively is a new space in memory.

To avoid this behavior, you can import the copy library, and use copy.deepcopy to perform a deep copy of both datasets. A deep copy will assign a unique memory space to the object.